# System.UnauthorizedAccessException when accessing the SharePoint 2013 REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, exception-handling

When I try to load AJAX scripts into private site it runs with any problems, but when I do public site I have AccessException, I read a lot of it, and I found this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e9924aef-28df-43a4-8d79-a9d1532699c6/systemunauthorizedaccessexception-when-accessing-sharepoint-2013-rest-api?forum=sharepointsearch), where have same problem and found solution setting Barer. But I don´t know where I set barer, someone can help me where I should copy method of the solution given in link?

There is my js:

```
function MenuPopulate(url, listname, target) {
    var lang = "Espanol";
    if ((window.location.href.indexOf("lang=en") > 0)) {
        lang = "English";
    }
    // Getting our list items
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items?$select=Title,Enlace&$orderby=Posicion&$top=6&$filter=Idioma eq '" + lang + "'",
        method: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
         "X-RequestDigest": $("__REQUESTDIGEST").val() },
         contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            completeMenu(data, target);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failureMenu(data, target);
        }
    });
}
```

So first I think I should only add function like:

```
SharePointContextToken ContextToken = TokenHelper.ReadAndValidateContextToken(ContextTokenString, Request.Url.Authority);

                Uri sharepointUrl = new Uri(Request.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);

                //Get the AccessToken
                string AccessToken = TokenHelper.GetAccessToken(ContextToken,sharepointUrl.Authority).AccessToken;

                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(@"https://mysite-public.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists");
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);

                HttpWebResponse response =(HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());


function MenuPopulate(url, listname, target) {
    var lang = "Espanol";
    if ((window.location.href.indexOf("lang=en") > 0)) {
        lang = "English";
    }
    // Getting our list items
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items?$select=Title,Enlace&$orderby=Posicion&$top=6&$filter=Idioma eq '" + lang + "'",
        method: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
         "X-RequestDigest": $("__REQUESTDIGEST").val() },
         contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            completeMenu(data, target);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failureMenu(data, target);
        }
    });
}
```

This isn't working, can anyone help me there?

Comment: Have you already checked if current user has enough permission to list items?

Comment: Yes, user have all permissions, I call to microsoft and they confirm I have all right with permissions and they suggest the problem is with code @buttercup

Answer (score 0):

You need the cookie as a header when performing a request to SharePoint. You don't even need the "X-RequestDigest" header when only making a "GET" request.

Just add it here:

```
headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
           "Cookie": "FedAuth=" + FedAuth + "; rtFa=" + rtFa  }
```

You need to perform authentication in order to get the cookies. If you haven't done any authentication, you can try this one ->  http://paulryan.com.au/2014/spo-remote-authentication-rest/